# Create Bootstrap 2 popover on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Where I can view simple example of popover for boostrap 2 version?

Thanks.

Comment: Go to [Google](http://www.google.com).  Type: `twitter bootstrap popover` in the text box.  Click `Google Search`.

Answer (score 4):

#### You can get it at [Bootstrap Popovers](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

And the example code is:

```
$('#example').popover(options);
```

#### Options

[image: options]